# Why does Bootstrap 5.2.1 cause modal to hide when paging Datatable?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datatables

I have a [datatable](https://datatables.net/) inside a bootstrap v5.2.1 modal. When I open the modal and try to page through the data, the modal immediately hides itself. This does not happen with bootstrap v5.2.0.

Why does this happen?

Demos of datatables within bootstrap modals:

[BS v5.2.0 demo](http://jsfiddle.net/xcr3nmew/2/)

[BS v5.2.1 demo](http://jsfiddle.net/xcr3nmew/3/)

Snippet of BS v.5.2.1 code with the issue:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#example').DataTable({
    scrollY: "40vh",
    scrollCollapse: true,
    scroller: true,
    responsive: true
  });

  $(document).on('shown.bs.modal', '#modal', function() {
    $($.fn.dataTable.tables(true)).DataTable()
      .columns.adjust()
      .responsive.recalc()
      .scroller.measure();
  });

  $('#exampleModal').on('hide.bs.modal hidden.bs.modal', function(e) {
    //console.log(e);
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datatables/1.10.21/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datatables.net-bs5/1.12.1/dataTables.bootstrap5.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datatables.net-bs5/1.12.1/dataTables.bootstrap5.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/5.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/5.2.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>


<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal">
  Launch modal
</button>

<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <table id="example" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hovered" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Name</th>
              <th>Email</th>
              <th>Role</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>1</td>
              <td>a@a.com</td>
              <td>User</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>2</td>
              <td>b@b.com</td>
              <td>Admin</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>1</td>
              <td>a@a.com</td>
              <td>User</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>2</td>
              <td>b@b.com</td>
              <td>Admin</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>1</td>
              <td>a@a.com</td>
              <td>User</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>2</td>
              <td>b@b.com</td>
              <td>Admin</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>1</td>
              <td>a@a.com</td>
              <td>User</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>2</td>
              <td>b@b.com</td>
              <td>Admin</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>1</td>
              <td>a@a.com</td>
              <td>User</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>2</td>
              <td>b@b.com</td>
              <td>Admin</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>1</td>
              <td>a@a.com</td>
              <td>User</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>2</td>
              <td>b@b.com</td>
              <td>Admin</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>1</td>
              <td>a@a.com</td>
              <td>User</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>2</td>
              <td>b@b.com</td>
              <td>Admin</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>1</td>
              <td>a@a.com</td>
              <td>User</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>2</td>
              <td>b@b.com</td>
              <td>Admin</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>1</td>
              <td>a@a.com</td>
              <td>User</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>2</td>
              <td>b@b.com</td>
              <td>Admin</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>1</td>
              <td>a@a.com</td>
              <td>User</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>2</td>
              <td>b@b.com</td>
              <td>Admin</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you can check the event target on close event of the modal and cancel it if it came from pagination. or just use 5.2.0 instead. if you set it up as a snippet i will definitely try this workaround

Comment: @ITgoldman, thanks for the response. I have set up the code as a snippet and provided the event handler for you. I actually had tried this before I posted the question but I couldn't find where the event came from.

Comment: What happens if you use the [officially supported versions](https://datatables.net/download/index) of jQuery, DataTables, and Bootstrap 5? Maybe worth a check.

Comment: I couldn't do it. There's an issue of it in github though https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/37126 that resolved in https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/pull/37128 and it is considered fixed in the last few days. That means you can download from github directly and should work. . or go back to 5.2.0

Comment: Thank you. If you want you can post this as an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's an issue with this bootstrap version and the modal [(github)](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/37126). It resolved in [this pull request](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/pull/37128)  but not yet released. In the meantime you can go back to version 5.2.0.