# Unexpected hide bootstrap modal behavior every time remove the last item of array component

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-modal, vuejs3, bootstrap-5, vite

I have a requirement to remove dynamic item array under modal. Basically each item can be any component, in this case is a button. If the button is clicked then the item will be disappear. The weird things is whenever i remove the last item (just the last item), it will close the modal which is the behavior that i am not expecting.

In order to reproduce the issue you can follow this step:

- npm create vite@latest
- select the framework: **Vue** and variant: **Javascript**
- npm install bootstrap@5.2.1
- npm i --save-dev sass
- npm install
- npm run dev
- replace all content App.vue with this code

```
<template>

  <!-- Button trigger modal -->
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal">
    Launch demo modal
  </button>

  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
          <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">

          <button v-for="(item, index) in payload.items"
                  :key="index"
                  type="button"
                  class="btn btn-danger"
                  @click="removeItem(index)">Remove {{item.name}}{{item.index}}
          </button>

        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</template>

<script setup>

import 'bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss'
import "bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js";
import {reactive} from "vue";

const payload = reactive({
  items: [
    {index: 0, name: 'Hello',},
    {index: 1, name: 'Hello',},
    {index: 2, name: 'Hello',},
  ],
})

const removeItem = (index) => payload.items.splice(index, 1)

</script>
```

I already try to simplify the original use case in order to help you to answer my question. You need to refresh the browser to fill the item array back after remove all the items.

Comment: Bootstrap 5.2.1 has some [issues](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/37126) with the modal. try with 5.2.0.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does Bootstrap 5.2.1 cause modal to hide when paging Datatable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73859714/why-does-bootstrap-5-2-1-cause-modal-to-hide-when-paging-datatable)

Comment: Yes, your first reply already answer my question. Thanks!
Your second reply has no relation to my question, although maybe it has the same root cause problem